# Delete duplicates and preserving old ones using headers?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I need to eliminate similar duplicates. I have a column with the following values:

```
old1950
old1933
old1985
new_1950
new_1985
new_2008
```

After running the delete command should be left:

```
old1950
old1933
old1985
new_2008
```

As you can see the delete command should preserve the old ones.

All the number are preceded by a header 'old' or 'new' literally.

How I can achieve this goal?

---

Now I'm running the following code and it works ok, thanks to fthiella

```
 CREATE TABLE yourtable (
  `accountID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `deviceID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  col VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (`accountID`,`deviceID`)
  );

INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES
(1,1,'old1950'),
(1,2,'old1933'),
(1,3,'old1985'),
(1,4,'new_1950'),
(1,5,'new_1985'),
(1,6,'new_2008');

DELETE y1
FROM
  yourtable y1 INNER JOIN yourtable y2
  ON y1.col LIKE 'new_%' AND y2.col LIKE 'old%'
     AND SUBSTR(y1.col, 5)=SUBSTR(y2.col, 4)
```

Comment: You say that you're "*trying to add data to a table*", but your question only talks about deleting data.  If you're looking to insert new data, but ignore duplicates, create a `UNIQUE` constraint and use `INSERT IGNORE`.  Otherwise, if you're merely looking to delete records that have already been inserted, how do you identify which records are "old" and which are "new"?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you are right.

Comment: The data is in the data base but I can delete and re insert. As I say the old register haver literally the header 'old' and the new ones the header 'new'; so if I want I can delete using LIKE 'new%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
DELETE y1
FROM
  yourtable y1 INNER JOIN yourtable y2
  ON y1.col LIKE 'new%' AND y2.col LIKE 'old%'
     AND SUBSTR(y1.col, 4)=SUBSTR(y2.col, 4)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c46c/1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I seems to work but in my table doesn't work cause is in safe mode, so y need to provide some key column in a WHERE clause. The KEY columns are AccountID and DeviceID, where I should add this in your example?

Comment: @e_blue can you disable safe mode using `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;` before the update query, and then enable it again with `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;` after the query? because LIKE 'something%' can make use of an index if it exists, but I doubt that SUBSTR can... let me think...

Comment: I just disable safe mode(SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;) then run it but with 0 rows affected.

Comment: @E_Blue if you try to do a `SELECT y1.* FROM ..same as above..` does it return anything? i would then try to remove a condition at a time to see wich one makes the query return 0 rows...

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the header of new is 'new_' not 'new'; so I change the query, I'm going to update my post using the right one